# Как с помощью JavaScript суммировать все буквы в слове в соответствии с их положением в алфавите

Tags: javascript

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться. Мне нужно узнать сумму всех букв в слове “водолаз”. Известно, что каждая буква алфавита прикреплена к определенной цифре, например,  цифра, привязанная к букве “в” равна 9, а цифра, привязанная к буква “з” равна 27. 
Понимаю, что задача легкая и ее можно решить логически в уме и что цифра , к которой привязана каждая буква алфавита, увеличивается каждый раз на 3. Я не могу понять, как это превратить в JavaScript

Comment: буква “з” равна 9

Comment: @Igor _цифра , к которой привязана каждая буква алфавита, увеличивается каждый раз на 3._ (хотя все равно непонятно, как получается 27, и чему равна 'а')

Comment: извините, пожалуйста, я исправил ошибку в тексте

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример для русского алфавита. Символы в нижнем регистре

```js
class Alphabet {
    constructor(num) {
        this.chars = [];
        for(let j=1072, index=1; j<=1103; j++, index++) {
            if(index == 7) index++;
            this.chars[String.fromCharCode(j)] = index * num;
        }
        this.chars['ё'] = 7 * num;
    }
    getSumIndexChars(str) {
        let r = 0;
        for(let j=0; j<str.length; j++) {
            r += this.chars[str[j]];
        }
        return r;
    }
}
console.log(new Alphabet(1).getSumIndexChars('водолаз'));
console.log(new Alphabet(3).getSumIndexChars('водолаз'));
```

Comment: Евгений Федак, спасибо! не подскажете , откуда берутся значения  1072 и 1103?

Comment: @max, эти коды символов берутся из закодированных символов таблицы UTF (для js UTF-16).

Comment: уже разобрался, спасибо Вам за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

Буква «ё» всё усложняет:

```js
function getCharValue(c) {
  const a = 'а'.charCodeAt(0);
  if (c < 'е') return (c.charCodeAt(0) - a + 1) * 3
  else if (c == 'ё') return 21;
  return (c.charCodeAt(0) - a + 2) * 3;
}

function getWordValue(w) {
  return w.toLowerCase().split('').reduce((sum, c) => sum + getCharValue(c), 0);
}

console.log(getWordValue('водолаз'));
```

Comment: Yaant, огромное спасибо, читаю код,  не очень понимаю, что именно проверяется в этом If-statement ?  `if (c < 'ж') return (c.charCodeAt(0) - a + 1) * 3` обьясните, пожалуйста

Comment: Ну, в таблице символов буквы от «а» до «я» (без «ё») идут подряд. 
Соответственно, до буквы «ё» значение вычисляется как `(<код символа> - <код «а»> + 3)`, а после «ё» - как `(<код символа> - <код «а»> + 6)`. Но там была ошибка, должно быть `if (c < 'е') ...`.

Comment: @ Yaant, очень Вам благодарен, спасибо за разьяснение

Comment: @ Yaant,я увидел - огромное спасибо!